# Get last number from string

Tags: java

I want to get the last character of a string and if it's a even number to do different actions based on that. Simple example:

```
Server_3
```

First I want to get the last value 3

```
            String str = "Server_3";
            str.charAt(str.length()-1)
```

The problem is next how to construct the logic to have different cased based on that is this a even number or not. Can you help me to complete this?

Comment: ```if (Integer.valueOf(str.charAt(str.length()-1))%2 == 0) {\\even}```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct code is:

```
if (Integer.valueOf(str.charAt(str.length()-1) + "") % 2 == 0) {
    // Even logic
} else {
    // Odd logic
}
```

Or.... to reduce method calls and the get rid of the funky string concatenation:

```
if ((str.charAt(str.length()-1) - '0') % 2) {
    // Even logic
} else {
    // Odd logic
}
```

Comment: Using concatenation with `""` is not very elegant, you can use `String.valueOf(char)` instead.

Comment: Note that it would technically still work without the cast since `Integer.valueOf('1')` is `49`, which is even. Not a very good idea though.

Comment: +1'd Yeah, I thought of that as well but if you want to do something other than checking for evens (e.g. divisibility by 3), it wouldn't be reliable anymore. It doesn't hurt if we handle all cases in general anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Convert to integer and check for even

```
if(Integer.valueOf(str.charAt((str.length()-1) + "") % 2 ==0) {
    // do your work here
}
```

Comment: sorry for the mistake, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the modulo (`%`) operator: `i % 2` is 0 if `i` is even, and 1 if `i` is odd.